# c# dynamic variable with ?? and ? operator

Tags: c#

Sorry for asking a simple question,
I'm new to Azure Function HTTPtriggers with C#,
Anyone know what is the `name = name?? data?.name;`  mean in c# ?

```
        string name = req.Query["name"];
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;
```

Comment: If `name` was not `null` take that value, if it was, try taking `data?.name`. The expression `data?.name` looks if `data` was `null`, if so then `null` is returned, otherwise the value of `data.name` is returned.

Comment: You have 2 questions, both are answered with an extremely simple Google search: "c# double question mark" and "c# question mark with dot". Or just the C# documentation

Comment: Thank you for the comment @AlexeyLarionov

Comment: Just want to make sure how both of them put together mean. thank you for all the explanation, and relate question link, @CamiloTerevinto

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It essentially means

```
if name is not null
  set name to name
else
  if data is null
    set name to null
  else
    set name to data.name
```

The second operator ([`?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)) avoids a `NullReferenceException` by returning null instead of trying to use the access modifier. The first ([`??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)) returns the first operand if the value is not null, otherwise it returns the second.

Note that neither of these are specific to `dynamic` or Azure.

It could also have been written as

```
if ((name == null) && (data != null))
{
   name = data.name;
}
```

Comment: your second algorithm will not set the null value if all checks are false ;)

Comment: If name is not null then name is set to itself. If name is null and data is null, then there's no need to set name to null again.

Comment: you're correct, it won't affect anything, just for the sake of completeness

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it is much more clear. how it works.

Comment: _The first (??) returns the first operand if the value is null_ That's wrong, it returns the first operand if it's not null.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, fixed.